# Sorting with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Am newbie to SQL Server. In that i need to sort the following data

```
1, 1AB, 1AA, 20, 3C, 4D
```

**into**

```
1, 1AA, 1AB, 3C, 4D, 20.
```

My coding is of

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE name = 'getIntPortion')
 DROP FUNCTION getIntPortion
GO    
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getIntPortion ( @inputVarchar varchar(255))
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN
 WHILE(PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @inputVarchar) ) > 0
 BEGIN
 --then remove that one character, then continue
 SET @inputVarchar = REPLACE(@inputVarchar
 , SUBSTRING(@inputVarchar, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @inputVarchar), 1)
 , '')
 END
 RETURN @inputVarchar
END

SELECT km_ph_act_chapt_no FROM [KM_DB].[dbo].[km_ph_act_chapters]
ORDER BY CONVERT(INT, dbo.getIntPortion(km_ph_act_chapt_no))
```

For this Alpha is not ordering... Hopefully waiting for reply.

Thanks and Regards,

Asker

Comment: Its sorting with NUmeric... But Not in the above order i have mentioned.

Comment: Can you explain the algorithm you're trying to sort by?  Are you trying to sort by the numeric portion as a number, and then by alpha within a number?

Comment: Hi Steven, I have to sort with Alpha within a Number

Comment: If the rows had two columns, one for the int part, one for the varchar part, it would be easy

Comment: Jodrell: Actually i need to sort only by the chapter Number. So consider like.. Chapter 1, Chapter 1B, Chapter 2 etc...,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your function works correctly, change the order by to

```
SELECT km_ph_act_chapt_no FROM [KM_DB].[dbo].[km_ph_act_chapters] 
ORDER BY CONVERT(INT, dbo.getIntPortion(km_ph_act_chapt_no)) ,
   km_ph_act_chapt_no
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
ORDER BY CONVERT(INT, dbo.getIntPortion(km_ph_act_chapt_no)), km_ph_act_chapt_no;
```

But I would recommend against using a scalar function like this.

Answer (score 1):

add a secondary sort so that it will sort the letters after you have sorted by the leading number

e.g

```
SELECT km_ph_act_chapt_no FROM [KM_DB].[dbo].[km_ph_act_chapters]
ORDER BY CONVERT(INT, dbo.getIntPortion(km_ph_act_chapt_no)), km_ph_act_chapt_no
```